# Annotation Validation not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation, annotations

Please help me on the following code. The Model class is using `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotation`:

```
namespace Proj.Models
{
    public class Customer
    {
        [Required]
        public string CustomerID{get;set;}

        [Required]
        public string CustomerName{get;set;}
    }
}
```

I have created a controller using this model, the action method being:

```
public class Customer:Controller
{
    public ActionResult Details()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

The razor view is Details.cshtml, having following markup and code:

```
@model Proj.Models.Customer

<form method="post">

@Html.EditorForModel()

<button>Submit!!</button>

</form>
```

However, when I click submit, no validation errors are seen as expected.

Comment: make sure you have included Microsoft validation scripts, jquery

Comment: That is irrelevant because server-side validation doesn't require JS. You won't get the benefit of client-side validation but the postback will indeed show error messages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a method which takes your model as input like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(Customer customer)
{
    return View();
}
```

The `[HttpPost]` ensures that the method is only called on POST requests.

Comment: This one is superb. http://www.amazon.com/Pro-ASP-NET-MVC-3-Framework/dp/1430234040/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&qid=1354171626&sr=8-2&keywords=pro+asp.net+mvc Not for absolute beginners but if you have at least a basic background (which you certainly appear to) it is really wonderful. The MVC 4 version is coming out in a couple of weeks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create editor template for your model. By default no validation messages will be emitted. Inside your editor template, you will have to use `@ValidationMessageFor` for your `Required` fields.

Hope this helps.